# ampersands in url read as semicolon by php explode()

Tags: php, explode, html-encode

I want to allow my users to create a url link and label in a single field, like:

> Register Now; www.abc123.com

or just

> www.abc123.com

my code looks like this:

```
$cta_array = explode(";",  $field ) ;
if( count( $cta_array ) > 1 ){
  $cta = '<a href="'.esc_url( $cta_array[1] ).'" class="button '.$color.'">'.esc_html( $cta_array[0] ).'</a>';
}
else{
  $cta = '<a href="'.esc_url( $field ).'" class="button '.$color.'">Select</a>';
}
return $cta;
```

Only problem is if the url they enter has query strings with ampersands, the ampersands get treated as semicolons by the explode() function so if they enter

> Book Now; http://www.abc123.com/scripts/WebObjects.dll/AAAOnline?association=CAA&club=272

$cta_array variable returns this:

```
Array
```

(
    [0] => Book Now
    [1] =>  http://www.aaa.com/scripts/WebObjects.dll/AAAOnline?association=CAA&amp;
    [2] => club=272
)

I think its converting the '&' to `&amp;` and that semicolon is used as the delimiter but i'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried replacing &amp; with & before exploding?

Comment: `explode()` does not convert ampersands into its html escape. That was already there. What does your `esc_url()` function do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced the `&amp;` with & before exploding

```
$cta_array = explode( ';', str_replace( '&amp;', '&', $cta_array[0]) );
```

That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your users to use other delimiter such as comma. 
Or change delimiter programmatically.

```
$cta_array = explode(“|”,  str_replace(‘;’,’|’,$field));
```

Comment: Hi just replaces the semicolons in the &amp; to |. @developerwjk comment above solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than only replacing the `&amp;` a more complete solution would be to decode all html special characters

```php
$cta_array = explode(';', htmlspecialchars_decode($field));
```